# Property accessors vs. Map set method

Tags: javascript

Is there a way for the following code to either

1. raise an error on `m[k] = v` or
2. make the call `m[k] = v` automatically translate to `m.set(k, v)`

I would prefer solution 1. if possible.

```
// Imagine I write that somewhere
const m = new Map();
m.set("a", "alice");

// And at some point someone else write:
m["b"] = "bob";    // m = Map { 'a' => 'alice', b: 'bob' }
// Expecting "bob" to appear here: 
for (const [k, v] of m){
    console.log(k, v);
}
```

Note that when I say *someone else*, this other person could simply be me in the near future. Ideally I would like to have a solution that only modifies  the instantiation `const m = new Map()`. For example to something like `const m = safe(new Map())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just prevent properties being added you can use:

```
 Object.freeze(map);
```

However, that won't throw an error. To be able to throw an error on a property access you have to use a Proxy, however as that does not work on Maps directly (as they got internal properties that do not get reflected through the Proxy) you'd have to mirror all methods in an object, and use the Proxy on that:

```
 function safe(map) {
  return new Proxy({
    get(k) { return map.get(k); },
    set(k, v) { return map.set(k, v); }
    // .... others
 }, {
   set() { throw new Error("property setter on Map"); }
 });
}
```

You could also trap the Proxies getter to directly link to the Map (not sure about side effects though):

```
function safe(map) {
  return new Proxy({ }, {
   set() { throw new Error("property setter on Map"); },
   get(target, prop, receiver) {
    return typeof map[prop] === "function" ? map[prop].bind(map) : map[prop];
   }
  });
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Just because I'm lazy, is there a way to have the delegation to the `map` object automatic (by controlling the access to method/properties)? Anyway, I'm maybe asking too much, for now this is perfect! (maybe you can add a link to the lists of Map's properties/methods I'll have to delegate — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Map_instances.

Comment: `set: (k, v) => map.set(k, v),` will save me a bit of work, I wonder why I can't just write `set: map.set`.

Comment: @cglacet you could write `set: map.set.bind(map)` you have to keep the context with it

Comment: @cglacet I guess I saved you some work with the latest edit :)

Comment: That's just perfect, that also very close to what could be done in python (i'm actually surprised how similar this look). Should I really be concerned by any side effect? I don't see what could go wrong.

Comment: @cglacet I can't think of a scenario, but I cannot guarantee that without extensive testing ...

Answer (score 0):

you can use [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Proxy)

```js
let m = new Map();
m["a"] = "alice";

m = new Proxy(m, {      
  set(target, name, receiver) { throw "Setting values is forbidden!"; }
});

console.log(m["a"]);  // you can read value

m["b"] = "bob";       // setting value will throw exception
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work as expected, if I call `m.set("a", "alice");` I get an error `TypeError: Method Map.prototype.set called on incompatible receiver [object Object]`. It looks like the proxy modified the type from `Map` to `Object` (I have no idea how proxies work, I'll have a look at it).

Comment: @cglacet May be I don't understand your question - so you want to `m.set("k","v")` works but `m[k]=v` raise exception?

Comment: Yes exactly! Also if that works as I think it does, I can add set/get methods in the proxy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Proxy object. Instantiate it with the first argument being an instantiation of whatever Map you want.

```
const m = new Proxy(new Map(), {
    get(target, name, receiver) {
        return target.get(name);
    },
    set(target, name, receiver) {
        // 1. Comment in to allow error to be thrown.
        // throw new Error(`Cannot set property for ${name}`);

        // 2. Comment in to allow setting via bracket syntax.
        // target.set(name, receiver);
    }
});
```